# What means the "$" behing class name when doing a Dump Java Heap on android studio?

Tags: android

Sorry I can't upload an image...

So when I do a dump I can see for someone of my classes :

myActivity---------------------- 1 (total count)--- 1 (heap count)

myActivity$1-------------------- 1 (total count)--- 1 (heap count)

myActivity$2-------------------- 1 (total count)--- 1 (heap count)

I have a cout of 1 but I can see my class 3 times... Is it a leak memory or something ?

And other question...

I'm doing tests of robustness ans maybe it's a stupid question... I'm entering and exiting many times an activity. I can see the count increase. But when the garbage collector decide to pass (or when I launch it on android studio...) occurrences disappears and I can see only one. So that seems to be normal. BUT between this gap, when the garbage collector has not past, my app is vulnerable to an out of memory depending on so how the users manipulate it. How to prevent this behavior ?

And last question...

Is 100Mo (in android studio monitor...) of ram too much for an app ?

Thanks !

Comment: after $ is name of inner class ... number means anonymouse one

Comment: Please do not ask multiple unrelated questions in one post.

Answer (score 1):

These usually refer to anonymous inner classes.

Comment: Hi can you tell me a little bit more ? Is it bad ?

Comment: @Johnduff There is nothing bad about it. The class has no name (since it's anonymous), so the compiler creates a name by taking the enclosing class name and appending `$` followed by a sequential number. That's all it means.

Comment: Ahh ok thanks :) And do you have an answer for my added questions :-/